# iOS13 UICollectionView not respecting size returned in delegate method for cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios13

In iOS13, i return

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return collectionView.bounds.size
}
```

but the displayed cell is hugged horizontally and not fullwidth... this wasn't happening before

is there any change that is responsible? why is this happening?

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: This is happening to me too. Have you figured out a fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262024/uicollectionview-always-auto-sizing-cells-not-using-sizes-returned-from-delegat

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In interface builder, set Estimated size to 'None' from 'Automatic'

[image]